# Updating one text box as text is typed in another text box, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a webpage using HTML and jQuery. And I am using webpy framework. I have two text boxes in my html/webpage. I want to display the contents of first textbox in second textbox meanwhile I type in first textbox. How can I implement this using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuerys Change event handler (search for jQuery Change for full docs)

Something like this should be what you are after

```
$(function() {
    $('#txtbox1').change(function() {
       $('#txtbox2').val(this.value);
    });
});
```

EDIT - Even though this was accepted answer check out the answer provided by @Huske for a better way, both work but I thought I should point out his alternative.

Comment: The problem with change event is that it occurs after focus is lost or there is a change in a list box or drop down list. It does not trigger an event when key is released like keyup event.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$("#sourceText").keyup(function () {
    $("#destinationText").val($(this).val());
});
```

Regards